# Parse Json array into object

Tags: c#, json, parsing, deserialization

I am currently working with Json Deserializing code. Here is my problem:

In the Json file I encountered a array looks like this:

```
"location":[47.618832,-122.21599]
```

For which I can easily parse into a double array:

```
[DataMember(Name = "location")]
public double[] Location { get; set; }
```

But I want to generate a object in this case, lets call it `location` of  `Coordinate` type defined in someother namespace. It has constructor like this:

`public Coordinate(double lat, double long)`

So is there a way I can generate a Coordinate object directly in this case?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly but much cleaner way.

```
public class MyClass
{
       [DataMember(Name = "location")]
       public double[] Location { get; set; }

       public Coordinate Coordinate
       {
            get
            {
                  if(Location.Lenght > 2)
                  {
                        return new Coordinate() { Lat = Location[0], Lang = Location[1] };
                  }

                  return null;
            }
       }

}

public class Coordinate
{
      public double Lat { get; set;}
      public double Lang { get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just mark the parsed data as private and expose it the way you want to.

```
public class MyClass
{
   public struct Coordinate
   {
       public double Lat;
       public doubel Lon;
   }

   [DataMember(Name = "location")]
   private double[] _Location { get; set; }

   public Coordinate Location
   {
       get
       {
           return new Coordinate { Lat = _Location[0], Lon = _Location[1]};
       }
       set
       {
           double[0] = value.Lat;
           double[1] = value.Lon;
   }

}
```

I just threw this together and would probably make the Coordinate type immutable and make sure that I overrode the comparision of Equals and the == operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the [IDataContractSurrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.idatacontractsurrogate.aspx) interface which

> Provides the methods needed to substitute one type for another by the
>   DataContractSerializer during serialization, deserialization, and
>   export and import of XML schema documents (XSD).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with JSon directly but you could have a Coordinate property that the Location property gets/sets:

```
// Not affected by JSon deserialization
[ScriptIgnore]
public Coordinate Coordinate {get; set;}

// Serialized/Deserialized by JSon
public double[] Location { 
    get 
        {
            return new double[] {Coordinate.Latitude,Coordinate.Longitude};
        } 
    set
        {
            Coordinate = new Coordinate(value[0],value[1]);
        }
}
```

Of course you should add appropriate bounds checking, etc.